# Define annotation importing and customizing JPA annotations

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I have to define several entities and each time the annotations used are the same so I am wondering if it is possible to combine these annotation into one.

Eg.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table( name = "my_entity", schema = "tableschema" )
@EqualsAndHashCode( of = "id" )
@SequenceGenerator( name = "sequence_id", sequenceName = "sequence_id", schema = "tableschema" )
@Accessors( chain = true )
public class MyEntity {

}
```

So I would like to define one annotation which resume all these annotations and where I could change only table name, sequence's name and schema name.
Something like:

```
@Documented
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table
@EqualsAndHashCode( of = "id" )
@SequenceGenerator
@Accessors( chain = true )
public @interface CutomEntity {

    String tableName();

    String schemaName();

    String sequenceName();
}
```

And refer those parameters to each respective annotation.

Comment: You mean Java "meta annotations" ? So why not do that ? (assuming you are using JPA 2.2). https://datanucleus.wordpress.com/2017/05/25/dn-v5-1-meta-annotations/

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I’ll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Using metannotations is going to be straightforward. **Assuming you have Spring on your classpath, you can also pass parameters.** The solution for that is [`AliasFor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html).

You can check the doc for the full picture, but this is the relevant part:

```
@Documented
...
@Accessors( chain = true )
public @interface CutomEntity {

    @AliasFor(annotation = Table.class, attribute = "name")
    String tableName();

    @AliasFor(annotation = EqualsAndHashCode.class, attribute = "id")
    String sequenceName();

    // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I’ll try it later. How Spring will discovers the custom annotation? I think the magic behind `AliasFor` will work only if Spring intervenes.

Comment: I tried but as `@AliasFor` is not `@Repeatable` I have to duplicate everything eg for the `schema` attribute in `@Table` and `@SequenceGenerator`